# Database Date Queries

Tags: mysql, database, eloquent

I generate a report from my database using todays Day as my pivot point.

eg.

```
  $sub = Subscription::whereDay('startdate',Carbon::today())->get();
```

But some of the months that have 30days therefore i cant get the report for 31st.

Any solution is welcome 
thank you

Comment: And what would you like a database to return you, if it’s the 31st of March and you ask it for data from the 31st of February?

Comment: if the subscription date was 31st of january then it should produce the record or 31 january

Comment: the main problem is that when i generate the dates of february to march it doesnt contain 31st therefore am missing the report on 31st

Comment: Gotta admit I'mstill struggling with understanding the problem - your code asks for "today" which is only a single day but you seem to be talking about a range of dates. If you're using "today" to work out "the current month" then that's what you ask your database for: `WHERE MONTH(subscribedate) = MONTH(now())` (necessary YEAR() test omitted for clarity)

Comment: ok i generate a payment list each day according to the subscription day.
so if u subscribe on january 1st will will get paid on the 1st of february and march. so i use this code for getting the lists
$sub = Subscription::whereDay('startdate',Carbon::today())->get();

it works fine in some days except that some months have 31days whiles others have 30. SO my problem is if someone subscribes on january 31st since february have no 31st within its days am not able to get the list

Comment: ok i generate a payment list each day according to the subscription day.

Comment: What February day should a January 31st subscriber get paid on?

Comment: he should be paid on 31 february but you know february has no 31st day